# Constraints on UILabel not working

Tags: ios, swift

I've been struggling for the past hour with constraints in Swift. I can't for the life in me get my labels to look exactly how they do in the storyboard.

I currently have `vertical spacing, and horizontal spacing` on both my labels.

How it looks when loaded up:

[image: Screen shot when running]

How it looks in the storyboard:

[image: Screen shot of storyboard]

I'm using auto-layout but not size classes.

Any help is appreciated, constraints should be easy but they are a living hell.

Comment: Very few telepaths come to this website.  I'm afraid you'll have to post your actual code if you want any advice on it...

Comment: It's not the code, it's just the storyboard that I'm using

Comment: Constraints: http://s28.postimg.org/3lk5x2i99/Screen_Shot_2016_02_08_at_23_28_15.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put both labels into a `UIView`.

Next put the `UIView` in the center of the page. Add "Horizontally in container", "Width", "Height", and "Top Space" constraints to the `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say "I currently have vertical spacing, and horizontal spacing on both my labels."

To get the look you show I would select the 2 labels and choose editor>enclose in>view. Then set the spacing between the 2 labels to a constant value, and finally, select the new grouping view and center it horizontally in it's parent view.

Comment: Done what you said, here's what shows in the storyboard: http://s14.postimg.org/jhnc62ffk/Screen_Shot_2016_02_08_at_23_23_53.jpg and then this is when I run it: http://s14.postimg.org/jhnc62ffk/Screen_Shot_2016_02_08_at_23_23_53.jpg

Comment: Constraints: http://s28.postimg.org/3lk5x2i99/Screen_Shot_2016_02_08_at_23_28_15.png

Comment: DennisTurn your storyboard and run time images are the same.